# Install4j: Create shortcuts "Create program group" in Linux doesn't work

Tags: install4j

In install4j, when I "Create program group" with the Add button (Add File link or Add URL link)
it works fine in Windows , but it doesn't work in Linux (no shortcut is created in Debian)

Someone can help me ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The launcher integration on Linux only works for launchers. The additional program group entries are only created on Windows.

Comment: Thanks. So, I think I'll call a Linux script to create shortcuts with the  value of {sys.symlinkDir}

Comment: The same issue is found in Windows Server 2012. The new version of install4j will correct it ?

Comment: No, that should work. Check the file .install4j/installation.log after the installation. You should see the file installations of the program group entries.

Comment: You're right. All shorcuts are created in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\{myapplication}. But how can we pin them in the start menu (windows 8 or windows server 2012) ?

Comment: As of 5.x, install4j does not have an action for adding applications to the start screen.